# Why do two methods of numpy array multiplication give different answers?

Tags: python, numpy

In this small example the two "res" variables give different results. Can someone explain why this is? I expect them to both return roughly 5.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist1 = np.random.normal(100., 10., 10000)
dist2 = np.random.normal(0.05, 0.005, 10000)

res1 = dist1
res1 *= dist2

res2 = dist1 * dist2

print np.median(res1)
print np.median(res2)

# 4.986893617080765
# 0.24957162692779786
```

Comment: Did you check `dist1` before performing the second multiplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res1 = dist1` does **not** copy `dist1`. You are modifying it in place with `*=` hence those are two different operations.

Use `copy` to copy the array:

```
>>> dist1 = np.random.normal(100., 10., 10000)
>>> dist2 = np.random.normal(0.05, 0.005, 10000)
>>> 
>>> res1 = dist1.copy()
>>> res1 *= dist2
>>> 
>>> res2 = dist1 * dist2
>>> 
>>> print(np.median(res1))
4.970902419879373
>>> print(np.median(res2))
4.970902419879373
```

---

Just a tip: "variables" in python are just *names* (i.e. references) for objects. They do *not* represent a memory location. So doing:

```
res1 = dist1
```

You are simply giving a new name to the object whose name is `dist1` and now this object has two names (`res1` and `dist1`) and can be accessed by both.

When the object is immutable the difference between names/references and values is hard to see, but the difference is fundamental when dealing with mutable objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think this solves my problem in my main code.

It does seem weird to me that in my example you can replace the numpy arrays with floats and the two methods give 5. Why would an array of floats be mutable but a single float be immutable?
I can't believe I've never had this issue before.

Comment: @Rob In python numbers are immutable yes.  This is true in Java too! and other languages as well. Objects like arrays/lists/sets/maps etc that have mutable size tend to be mutable because copying them whenever they are passed as argument/assigned to a variable would cause a major reduction in performance. IMHO I prefer immutable objects because they are easier to reason about and you avoid race conditions by design. Yes sometimes they are less efficient but I think you should optimize only when you need to and after careful consideration.